# Saving excised data from dplyr functions: how to prevent conflict/overwrite

Tags: r, dplyr

EDIT: More complete explanation, as requested:
This is going to be hard to explain if you don't understand what I'm trying to do in the first place. When you are chaining, a lot of times you want to focus operations on only part of the data (certain rows, summary tables, column names, etc). When you are done, you often want to use incorporate these changes into the original data. However, this is impossible to do without disrupting the flow of the chain. These functions can allow you to do this. However, copies of the original data are stored in a location called the bank. Also, in order to reincorporate rows correctly, save rows and load rows utilize a new variable called index. Both bank and index could be accidentally modified during the chain causing problems. Also, what if there are existing variables called bank and index? Is there away to avoid these problems?

Many dplyr operations result in a loss of data. This is a system such that this data can be saved and restored. Save will be a string to identify a chunk of excised data. This data will be stored in list form in a bank. Note that this was inspired by mutate_if by skranz.

My question is: how to better handle the bank and the index such that these variables will not be overwritten or interfere with existing variables

```
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)

bank = NULL

save_rows = function(FUN)
  function(data, save, ...) {
    data$index = 1:nrow(data)
    results = data %>% FUN(...)
    bank[[save]] <<-
      data %>%
      anti_join(results %>% select(index))
    results}

load_rows = function(data, save)
  data %>% 
  bind_rows(bank[[save]]) %>%
  arrange(index) %>%
  select(-index)

save_all = function(FUN)
  function(data, save, ...) {
    bank[[save]] <<- data
    data %>% FUN(...)
  }

load_all = function(data, save)
  bank[[save]] %>% full_join(data)

change_names = function(data, save) {
  bank[[save]] <<- data
  data %>% colnames
}

attach_names_to = function(colnames, save) {
  bank[[save]] %>% 
    set_colnames(colnames)
}

#example
library(stringr)

a = c(1, 1, 2, 3)
b = c("my_momma", "my_momma", "takes_care", "of_me")
c = c("you", "you", "and", "me")

data_frame(a, b, c) %>%
  save_rows(filter)("filter", a == 1) %>%
  mutate(c = paste("baby", c, sep = "_")) %>%
  load_rows("filter") %>%
  save_rows(slice)("slice", 1) %>%
  mutate(b = "my_papa") %>%
  load_rows("slice") %>%
  group_by(a) %>%
  save_all(summarize)("summarize", n = n()) %>%
  load_all("summarize") %>%
  save_all(distinct)("distinct", a) %>%
  mutate(B = b %>% str_replace_all("_", " ")) %>%
  select(a, B) %>%
  load_all("distinct") %>%
  change_names("data") %>%
  paste("2", sep = "") %>%
  attach_names_to("data")
```

Comment: It is not clear that what you are trying to do makes sense, and your actual question is vague and nonspecific. Can you clarify the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, well here's version 3. I've solved the interference issue by allowing users to specify their own name for the bank and the index.

```
library(stringr)
library(stringi)
library(dplyr)
library(dplyrExtras)
library(pipeR)
library(lazyeval)
library(gtools)

construct_bank_index = defmacro(bank, index, expr = {

  bank = list("NULL" = NULL)

  old_bank = function() length(bank)
  new_bank = function() length(bank) + 1

  old_index = function() paste(index, old_bank(), sep = "")
  newIndex = function() paste(index, new_bank(), sep = "")

  select_old_index = function(data) data %>>%
    select_(old_index())
  remove_old_index = function(data) data %>>%
    select_(paste("-", old_index()))

  focus = function(data) {
    data[[newIndex()]] = 1:nrow(data)
    bank[[new_bank()]] <<- data
    data
  }

  restore = function(zoom) {
    restoreData = 
      bank[[old_bank()]] %>>%
      remove_old_index %>>%
      left_join(zoom)
    bank[[old_bank()]] <<-NULL
    restoreData
  }

  restore_rows = function(zoom) {
    restoreData = 
      bank[[old_bank()]] %>>%
      anti_join(zoom %>>% select_old_index()) %>>%
      bind_rows(zoom) %>>%
      remove_old_index()
    bank[[old_bank()]] <<-NULL
    restoreData
  }
})

#example

construct_bank_index(bank, "index")

options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

characters = c("1st", "2nd", "3rd", "other_value") %>>%
  rep(10) %>>%
  (data.frame(value = ., type = "character"))
numerics = c("1", "2", "3", ".") %>>%
  rep(10) %>>%
  (data.frame(value = ., type = "numeric"))
data = bind_rows(characters, numerics)

abbrevs = data_frame(
  value = c("1st", "2nd", "3rd"),
  full = c("first_value", "second_value", "third_value"))

results =
  data %>>%
  focus %>>%
    group_by(value) %>>%
    summarize(n = n(), type = first(type)) %>>%
    focus %>>%
      filter(type == "character") %>>%
      left_join(abbrevs) %>>%
      mutate_if(is.na(full), full = value) %>>%
      mutate(full = full %>>%
               str_replace_all("_", " ") %>>%
               stri_trans_totitle()) %>>%
    restore_rows %>>%
  restore %>>%
  mutate_if(!is.na(full), value = full) %>>%
  select(-full)
```

Answer (score 2):

I fail to see the advantage of your approach over the approach taken by `dplyrExtras`. Most of your code can be rewritten in either `dplyr` or `dplyrExtras`. See below to see how your example can be implemented without your extra functions.

Also, it is usually a bad idea to use `<<-`. If you really want to develop your approach further, perhaps you could use an approach that's similar to `options()`. See for instance `?igraph:::igraph.options` for an example of this.

And finally, your way of renaming does not preserve groups. In your example, the final grouping is after `a`, but there is no `a` in the data.

Finally, here's an alternative to your example:

```
# to get dplyrExtras
library(devtools)
install_github(repo="skranz/dplyrExtras")
require(dplyrExtras)
# the code that does the same as your example (except the final grouping)
data_frame(a, b, c) %>%
  mutate_if(a == 1,  c = paste("baby", c, sep = "_"))  %>%
  mutate_if(1, b = "my_papa") %>%
  group_by(a) %>%
  mutate(n = n()) %>% 
  mutate(B = b %>% str_replace_all("_", " ")) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  do(set_colnames(., paste0(colnames(.), "2"))) %>%
  group_by(a2)
```

Comment: Mutate_if is great, but it only allows you do to one operation on the table subset: mutate. What if you want to do other things? Merge, for example? Or a whole sequence of other operations? The operation str_replace_all takes a fair bit of time, and if you have data with a lot of redundancy, summarizing, conducting a sequence of string operations (say, recapitalization, replacing abbreviations, etc), and then remerging can save a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

Your strategy is needlessly complicated, in all cases much simpler approaches exist. Instead of

```
data_frame(a, b, c) %>%
  save_rows(filter)("filter", a == 1) %>%
  mutate(c = paste("baby", c, sep = "_")) %>%
  load_rows("filter")
```

use something like:

```
d <- data_frame(a, b, c)
d %>%
  mutate(c = ifelse(a == 1, paste("baby", c, sep = "_"), c))
```

and instead of

```
d %>%
  save_rows(slice)("slice", 1) %>%
  mutate(b = "my_papa") %>%
  load_rows("slice")
```

use something like

```
d %>%
    mutate(b = ifelse(1:n() == 1, "my_papa", b))
```

instead of

```
d %>%
  group_by(a) %>%
  save_all(summarize)("summarize", n = n()) %>%
  load_all("summarize")
```

use

```
d %>%
group_by(a) %>%
mutate(n = n())
```

Comment: See the comments on shadow's answer.

Comment: I did, that's why I un-deleted this answer, because it shows a more flexible approach that doesn't rely on mutate_if.

Comment: I agree that my system is clunky. I posted it on here not to be told it's clunky but for help in improving it. Mutate with ifelse, mutate_if, and grouping without summarizing are all very limited in scope. There are all sorts of things that you might want to do with a subset or a feature of data. Instead of finding an individual work around for each potential possibility, it would be great to have an easy and seamless way to directly access the subset itself, do any kind and number of operations you want, and reincorporated the original data, all in the context of a dplyr chain.

Comment: This particular strategy could be applied to all sorts of features of data: row names, factor labels, attributes, etc.

Comment: @bramtayl If your question is about where to store things so they don't interfere/get interfered with by the user then I suggest asking in a separate question. As this question currently stands my answer is "don't do that".

Answer (score 0):

I still think that the approach taken by `mutate_if` is the way to go. But it seems that you are right that summarizing and re merging can be faster for some examples. My preference would be to use functions similar to `mutate_if` to deal with that case. Below I show my approach for a `mutate_group` function together with some benchmark tests.

```
require(dplyr)
# mutate_group function
mutate_group <- function(df, ...){
  .dots = lazyeval::lazy_dots(...)
  groups <- groups(df)
  # grouping variables defined
  mdf <- df %>% 
    mutate_(.dots = setNames(names(.dots), paste0(".group.", names(.dots))))
  mdf %>% 
    group_by_(.dots = paste0(".group.", names(.dots))) %>% 
    summarize_() %>% 
    ungroup %>%
    mutate_(.dots=.dots) %>% 
    right_join(mdf, by=paste0(".group.", names(.dots))) %>% 
    select_(.dots = c(paste0("-.group.", names(.dots)), paste0("-", names(.dots), ".y"))) %>%
    rename_(.dots = setNames(paste0(names(.dots), ".x"), names(.dots)))   %>%
    group_by_(.dots=groups)
}
```

And now for the benchmarking:

```
require(microbenchmark)
# testing 1
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(x = sample(letters[1:4], 1e6, replace=TRUE), 
                 y = runif(1e6))
#  
microbenchmark(
  r1 <- df %>% mutate(x = gsub('a', 't', x))
  ,
  r2 <- df %>% mutate_group(x = gsub('a', 't', .group.x))
)
#
## Unit: milliseconds
##                                                             expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
## r1 <- df %>% mutate(x = gsub("a", "t", x))              324.9036 328.7171 337.6389 330.2874 345.2245 415.6200   100   b
## r2 <- df %>% mutate_group(x = gsub("a", "t", .group.x)) 117.0220 120.1766 128.9403 121.8053 135.4410 208.5801   100  a 
#
all.equal(r1, r2, check.attributes = FALSE)
## [1] TRUE
#
# testing 2
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(x = sample(letters[1:4], 1e6, replace=TRUE), 
                 y = sample(letters[1:4], 1e6, replace=TRUE), 
                 z = runif(1e6))
microbenchmark(
  r1 <- df %>% mutate(x = gsub('a', 't', x), 
                      y = gsub('b', 's', y))
  ,
  r2 <- df %>% mutate_group(x = gsub('a', 't', .group.x), 
                            y = gsub('b', 's', .group.y))
)
## Unit: milliseconds
##                                                                                       expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
## r1 <- df %>% mutate(x = gsub("a", "t", x), y = gsub("b", "s",      y))                     665.9306 674.2292 691.7966 682.0874 695.8887 776.9765   100   b
## r2 <- df %>% mutate_group(x = gsub("a", "t", .group.x), y = gsub("b",      "s", .group.y)) 150.9971 156.5910 177.6797 171.7907 177.9938 279.1329   100  a 
#
all.equal(r1, r2, check.attributes = FALSE)
## [1] TRUE
#
# testing 3
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(x = sample(letters[1:4], 1e6, replace=TRUE), 
                 y = sample(letters[1:4], 1e6, replace=TRUE), 
                 z = runif(1e6))
#  
microbenchmark(
  r1 <- df %>% group_by(y) %>% mutate(x = gsub('a', 't', x))
  ,
  r2 <- df %>% group_by(y) %>% mutate_group(x = gsub('a', 't', .group.x))
)
#
## Unit: milliseconds
##                                                                         expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
## r1 <- df %>% group_by(y) %>% mutate(x = gsub("a", "t", x))                   399.8765 405.0650 415.0338 408.3451 423.2523 494.0247   100   b
## r2 <- df %>% group_by(y) %>% mutate_group(x = gsub("a", "t",      .group.x)) 224.0281 231.9769 247.7521 244.8441 248.5926 319.9048   100  a 
#
all.equal(r1, r2, check.attributes = FALSE)
## [1] TRUE
```

Comment: Wow, that's really cool. I don't understand how the code works at all though.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, well here's a new version. The syntax is streamlined. I still haven't solved the issue with accidental interference.

```
library(stringr)
library(stringi)
library(dplyr)
library(dplyrExtras)
library(pipeR)

bank = list("dummy" = NULL)

oldBank = function() length(bank)
newBank = function() length(bank) + 1

oldIndex = function() paste("index", oldBank(), sep = "")
newIndex = function() paste("index", newBank(), sep = "")

selectOldIndex = function(data) data %>>%
  select_(oldIndex())
removeOldIndex = function(data) data %>>%
  select_(paste("-", oldIndex()))

focus = function(data) {
  data[[newIndex()]] = 1:nrow(data)
  bank[[newBank()]] <<- data
  data
}

restore = function(zoom) {
  restoreData = 
    bank[[oldBank()]] %>>%
    removeOldIndex %>>%
    left_join(zoom)
  bank[[oldBank()]] <<-NULL
  restoreData
}

restore_rows = function(zoom) {
  restoreData = 
    bank[[oldBank()]] %>>%
    anti_join(zoom %>>% selectOldIndex()) %>>%
    bind_rows(zoom) %>>%
    removeOldIndex()
  bank[[oldBank()]] <<-NULL
  restoreData
}

#example

options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

characters = c("1st", "2nd", "3rd", "other_value") %>>%
  rep(10) %>>%
  (data.frame(value = ., type = "character"))
numerics = c("1", "2", "3", ".") %>>%
  rep(10) %>>%
  (data.frame(value = ., type = "numeric"))
data = bind_rows(characters, numerics)

abbrevs = data_frame(
  value = c("1st", "2nd", "3rd"),
  full = c("first_value", "second_value", "third_value"))

results =
  data %>>%
  focus %>>%
    group_by(value) %>>%
    summarize(n = nrow(.), type = first(type)) %>>%
    focus %>>%
      filter(type == "character") %>>%
      left_join(abbrevs) %>>%
      mutate_if(is.na(full), full = value) %>>%
      mutate(full = full %>>%
               str_replace_all("_", " ") %>>%
               stri_trans_totitle()) %>>%
    restore_rows %>>%
  restore %>>%
  mutate_if(!is.na(full), value = full) %>>%
  select(-full)
```